Apache Proxy Error with long url (>1090 cars)
I have an error on my Apache Proxy server.
When an url is longer than 1090 chars we have 2 errors :
*[Thu Jun 13 21:06:12.680194 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 46823:tid 140407153346240] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 84.103.4.88:58296] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.202.41:80
[Thu Jun 13 21:06:12.680264 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 46823:tid 140407153346240] [client 84.103.4.88:58296] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /toto.php*

https://url.ext/test.html?code=0.AQwAJDMu3tBPA0i7lCy2LEWy9QpYbsxwWF5Hrz2Vu76zvO4MANc.AgABBAIAAADnfolhJpSnRYB1SVj-Hgd8AgDs_wUA9P_3Y6zJdaJIrc4scFbbFErN7BCueQ-2bx3G7cA-6dLRBgyIe_23b8xAx1wIQIWBNf45-5b67bkHSc56oWE5XdIP0BJffyrMJAOrTIhaHO95tQ8Rpmnluhzx3zqBjgi-Q3U6LBd__e49k0Qe48L0RGuIIysOJ2UcpRrgpmIp2AeLez51JjqfEKKsxB4jvhIxH5YMtTqnXxoFKuIiG8XzDFpXGPDxSWeZ1zhKcKgfB3yLsP2GtxJ0g97JSKLyFtft5CfYs0UHP0r_kduwGw--dDpnq1tmTQE1vqZhiX9mebWtALoqaM1ykbeD2RDL8bvVAy3Yu3vKmwOu4RwJjEXLojR1hrf8nsDLSTskxLRZWbAKFi7rZjxo30xaxTRPKXpv5Xrnd9MMrBQa8xKU52IdLUMvgEKD1mkvpKH871s1K2mRoB5LqVDamIgKcMpRqrfECIPCmVBDPfDjZJU12wzi5-S3965qkWWb1dIJNgQ4J0ar9THVBxCICrH-I2CgHfFuJ3Y7JXJIHG9tLcpyDDHWeXe5bKUBfvGRNEx0rsEp9L-ZpMeknx2ReCqToLFu_j-SL8LGYMGqSULtNJt2y5heRnns4vboAV5k_GX51y_fSvgPX-FhKqj9ERfirvXLQSwPJqpVdr88mGX9_9yKd-PP9MCg4LD6Mkd2oD8mpcOa6WmRN3EahoeMVM5qkS2Bt5Q4ATOOeWhJ_U_LPva_DRToswcKaTINSff6wWH5GCl7_be3Hk-gbZHtPNl-NaJsjuDqZcy8bjx5eU2mf3IARZWUFM7DeuOniPh3cP2t6MMT5Q1rqVmnJ2P_Me9xHFFMPqVt3-PIU5xlK7OpHO-111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 
Notice that I have tested lot of directives in conf but with no result.
LimitRequestFieldSize and LimitRequestLine that change anything here.
Thanks for helping
If somebody can help it would great !

I wonder how those cars got into your URLs... Generally I prefer using bikes on the web ;-)
